# Production build fails. Expected 3 arguments, but got 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'elipsis'
})
export class ElipsisPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(text, length, clamp) {
    text = text || '';
    clamp = clamp || '...';
    length = length || 30;

    if (text.length <= length) return text;

    let tcText = text.slice(0, length - clamp.length);
    let last = tcText.length - 1;

    while (last > 0 && tcText[last] !== ' ' && tcText[last] !== clamp[0]) last -= 1;

    // Fix for case when text dont have any `space`
    last = last || length - clamp.length;

    tcText = tcText.slice(0, last);

    return tcText + clamp;
  }

}
```

ng build command resulted in the following error:

ERROR in src/app/components/movies/movies.component.html(15,21): Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
src/app/components/movies/movies.component.html(38,21): Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
src/app/components/movies/movies.component.html(61,21): Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
src/app/components/movies/movies.component.html(83,21): Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.

```html
<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing__head">
        <h3 class="listing__title">Popular Movies</h3>
        <!-- <a class="listing__explore"><strong>Explore All</strong></a> -->
    </div>
    <p-carousel [value]="discover_movies_data" [numVisible]="6" [numScroll]="4" [circular]="false">
        <ng-template let-discovermovies pTemplate="item">
            <div class="listing-item-style" [routerLink]="['/movies/', discovermovies.id]">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="hover"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i> PLAY NOW</div>
                </div>
                <img *ngIf="discovermovies?.poster_path"
                    src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/{{discovermovies?.poster_path}}">
                <img *ngIf="!discovermovies?.poster_path" src="assets/images/default-movie.png">
                <h6>{{ discovermovies?.title | elipsis:22 }}</h6>
                <p class="rate"><i class="material-icons">star</i><span>{{discovermovies?.vote_average}}</span> /10
                </p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
</div>


    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing__head">
        <h3 class="listing__title">Upcoming Movies</h3>
        <!-- <a class="listing__explore"><strong>Explore All</strong></a> -->
    </div>
    
    <p-carousel [value]="upcoming_movies" [numVisible]="6" [numScroll]="4" [circular]="false">
        <ng-template let-coming_movies pTemplate="item">
            <div class="listing-item-style" [routerLink]="['/movies/', coming_movies.id]">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="hover"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i> PLAY NOW</div>
                </div>
                <img *ngIf="coming_movies?.poster_path" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/{{coming_movies?.poster_path}}">
                <img *ngIf="!coming_movies?.poster_path" src="assets/images/default-movie.png">
                <h6>{{ coming_movies?.title | elipsis : 22 }}</h6>
                <p class="rate"><i class="material-icons">star</i><span>{{coming_movies?.vote_average}}</span>/10
                </p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
</div>


    <div class="listing">
        <div class="listing__head">
        <h3 class="listing__title">Top Rated Movies</h3>
        <!-- <a class="listing__explore"><strong>Explore All</strong></a> -->
    </div>

    <p-carousel [value]="top_rated_movies_data" [numVisible]="6" [numScroll]="4" [circular]="false">
        <ng-template let-toprated pTemplate="item">
            <div class="listing-item-style" [routerLink]="['/movies/', toprated.id]">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="hover"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i> PLAY NOW</div>
                </div>
                <img *ngIf="toprated?.poster_path" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/{{toprated?.poster_path}}">
                <img *ngIf="!toprated?.poster_path" src="assets/images/default-movie.png">
                <h6>{{ toprated?.title | elipsis : 22 }}</h6>
                <p class="rate"><i class="material-icons">star</i><span>{{toprated?.vote_average}}</span>/10
                </p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
</div>


<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing__head">
        <h3 class="listing__title">Now Playing Movies</h3>
        <!-- <a class="listing__explore"><strong>Explore All</strong></a> -->
    </div>
    <p-carousel [value]="now_playing_movies" [numVisible]="6" [numScroll]="4" [circular]="false">
        <ng-template let-nowplaying pTemplate="item">
            <div class="listing-item-style" [routerLink]="['/movies/', nowplaying.id]">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="hover"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i> PLAY NOW</div>
                </div>
                <img *ngIf="nowplaying?.poster_path" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/{{nowplaying?.poster_path}}">
                <img *ngIf="!nowplaying?.poster_path" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/{{nowplaying?.poster_path}}">
                <h6>{{ nowplaying?.title | elipsis : 22 }}</h6>
                <p class="rate"><i class="material-icons">star</i><span>{{nowplaying?.vote_average}}</span>/10
                </p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is that your `movies.component`? Because according to the error messages, it's at least 83 lines long. Also, the error points at specific places in the template. Care to share, where exactly is `(15,21)`, for example?

Comment: now pls check this

Comment: OK. So the error appears on every line with the `elipsis` pipe. What's that?

Comment: how many arguments does elipsis pipe expect? Currently it receives only 2

Comment: i updated the elipsis code as well

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here's the problem:

```
export class ElipsisPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(text, length, clamp) {
    text = text || '';
    clamp = clamp || '...';
    length = length || 30;
```

`EllipsisPipe` *requires* 3 arguments, and TypeScript can't ignore that. Use optional parameters with default values:

```
  transform(text, length = 30, clamp = '...') {
```